# How to avoid early return on formidable functions in Node js

Tags: node.js, formidable

I used the following code to upload and read files in node js. It works as expected except the early return from the method. There the method returned before fire 'fileBegin' and 'file' events. Could you please tell me what do I need to change it to make it return only after the file is uploaded and processed?

```
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(req);
form.on('fileBegin', async function (name, file) {
...............

});
form.on('file', async function (name, file) {
...............

})
.on("end", function () {
...............
});

}
......................
......................
......................

 return "Success"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a middleware

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fileType = require('file-type')
const multiparty = require('multiparty')
const uploadMiddleware = (request, response, next) => {
      if (request.method !== 'POST') {
        next()
        return
      }

      const form = new multiparty.Form()
      form.parse(request, async (error, fields, files) => {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

         //  const file = files.file[0]
          // const buffer = fs.readFileSync(file.path)
          // request.file = your file 

          next()
        } catch (error) {
          return response.status(400).send(error)
        }
      })
    }
app.post('/upload', multipartUpload, yourController)
```

Comment: Thank you Fadi. I need to create form and event firing using foarmidable forms.

Comment: Thank you Fadi. But I need to use formiable forms to file upload and processed

Comment: The important part is to pass `next` function to the controller when you're don!